# How to disable the entire bean validation in JSF?

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation

I want to process JSR-303 validation myself, i.e., get validation factory and invoke validate method myself:

```
class FormBean {
    void saveForm() {
         if (! doValidate()) {
             FacesContext.addMessage(...);
             return;
         }
         ...
     }
     void doValidate() { ... }
 }
```

Is there any way to disable the bean validation integrated in JSF? (Not that `immediate="true"`, which will not only bypass the validation, but also bypass update-model phases)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can disable it by disabling the validator for the fields:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.name}">
  <f:validateBean disabled="true"/>
</h:inputText>
```

**Update**:
In order to disable the bean validation for every input field by default, try to set the context variable: **javax.faces.validator.DISABLE_DEFAULT_BEAN_VALIDATOR** with the value '***true***'

Comment: Well, I'd like to disable the validation of all inputs.

Comment: You can wrap multiple input components with `f:validateBean` too, like shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17503608/1725096